# RTC + Jenkins - Build only for changed components

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, ant, rational-team-concert

We are using RTC as source control management (SCM) and Jenkins for build environment. We configured Repository workspace under build configuration.
Suppose Repository workspace is have 50 component and user (developer) has changed one of these 50 component. If user want to build, he need to build full repository workspace and it will take some time right for loading and building a small change? 
We can save the time while for loading by uncheck the box for "Delete directory before loading” (under Jenkins job configuration), uncheck the "Delete the directory before loading" option to prevent a full load. In this case a reload would happen for those files which has changed either locally or in the remote workspace.
But while in the case of building we have to build full Repository workspace. Is there any way, where only the changed components are detected from repository workspace) and built, instead of loading & building all components.
Is anyone did this by writing some Ant script or Groovy?

Comment: Hi Raj, I'm looking for the same solution. By any chance have you found one?
Do let me know